# psexec Windows Server 2008 Firewall

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, pstools

I am trying to use psexec to run a program on my windows server 2008 boxes.  It returns with the message "Can't access myserver:  The network path was not found."

If I turn off Windows Server firewall, I can successfully run the command.

Can anyone help me with the specific settings I need to change in windows server 2008 firewall to get this to work?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

Here are the In Bound Connection rules that need to be enabled:

- Under "File and Printer Sharing"

  - Echo Request

    - ICMpv4-In
    - ICMpv6-In
  - NB-Datagram-In
  - NB-Name-In
  - NB-Session-In

Answer (score 1):

I'm still confused as to why psexec is the remote shell of choice when WinRM offers all of the same benefits but with a single port opening in the firewall.

It does need configuring but probably less than PSExec. No problems if you've settled on psexec already, I'm just offering additional options. :)

Really quickly you need to execute `winrm quickconfig` on the machine that you wish to control. This quickstart command alters a number of settings throughout the system so it's worth investigating if your security policies allow this before you run it.

Once run, you can use WinRS like this:

```
WinRS -r:Computername ipconfig
```

You can, if you don't already have permissions on the target system, run the command with other credentials.

```
WinRS -r:Computername -u:Username -p:Password ipconfig
```

You can also use PowerShell commands on remote machines configured for remote management. From within Powershell management

`Invoke-Command hostname {powershell-command}` or `icm hostname {powershell-command}`

If you have the right infrastructure, WinRM and WinRS can replace the need for psexec and the quickconfig command makes setup simple enough.

Cheers

Lewis